# Javascript forEach array method not changing object properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

Sorry, this may be obvious to some but can someone please explain to me why this function called by a click event does not take the current element in the array that is an object with a property of state:'active', change it to null, and then gets the next element in the array ,that is also an object, and change its state property to 'active', but instead throw an error message like 'Cannot set property 'state' of undefined'?

Thankyou in advance!

```
var array = [{
    state : 'active'
}, {
    state : null
}, {
    state : null
}];

document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    array.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
        if(element.state === 'active') {
            element.state = null;
            array[index+1].state = 'active';
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: on the last iteration in forEach, index will be array.length -1 ... array[index+1], which is array[array.length],  will be undefined, and thus have no property called state

Comment: ^ Jaromanda is right. Whenever the last Object in the Array is the active one, your `index+1` goes out of bounds, and you will see the `undefined` error. You will need to rework your logic to handle the last element in the Array appropriately (go backwards one, go back to the start, whatever is right for your application).

Comment: ahh ok... see I thought that the value of state for the second element would change and then the error would be thrown but I see why now. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not that it doesn't do it, it does do it, but then the loop continues and now the next element is "active". It does this until the last element throws and error because you are trying to access an index which is out of the array.

Try this:

```
var i = null;
array.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
    if(element.state === 'active') {
        i = index;
    }
});

if (i !== null && i + 1 < array.length) { 
    array[i].state = null;
    array[i+1].state = 'active';
}
```